# Gmail app doesn't send messages, gives strange logcat message

Tags: gmail

Recently, Gmail has stopped sending messages, storing drafts, or basically having anything to do with messages I create. Clicking the "send" button does nothing, and exiting the app doesn't auto-save the draft as expected. Instead, logcat shows the following error (every time I click the "send" button, for example):

```
W/MessageQueue(27786): Handler (com.android.internal.os.HandlerCaller$MyHandler) {4160e070} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
W/MessageQueue(27786): java.lang.RuntimeException: Handler (com.android.internal.os.HandlerCaller$MyHandler) {4160e070} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
W/MessageQueue(27786):  at android.os.MessageQueue.enqueueMessage(MessageQueue.java:320)
W/MessageQueue(27786):  at android.os.Handler.enqueueMessage(Handler.java:626)
W/MessageQueue(27786):  at android.os.Handler.sendMessageAtTime(Handler.java:595)
W/MessageQueue(27786):  at android.os.Handler.sendMessageDelayed(Handler.java:566)
W/MessageQueue(27786):  at android.os.Handler.sendMessage(Handler.java:503)
W/MessageQueue(27786):  at com.android.internal.os.HandlerCaller.sendMessage(HandlerCaller.java:86)
W/MessageQueue(27786):  at android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService$IAccessibilityServiceClientWrapper.onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityService.java:619)
W/MessageQueue(27786):  at android.accessibilityservice.IAccessibilityServiceClient$Stub.onTransact(IAccessibilityServiceClient.java:70)
W/MessageQueue(27786):  at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:404)
W/MessageQueue(27786):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

Does anyone have a hint at what might be causing this? I've uninstalled and reinstalled the app, deleted the /data/data/com.google.android.gm directory, nothing works. I can receive and interact with email fine, it's only sending and saving drafts that doesn't work, afaics.

Comment: What device? Is it rooted? What version of Android? Did you install anything recently that could cause this (add on for Gmail). Have you made any changes to the device?

Comment: What about a reboot – have you tried that (you didn't explicitely state)? Also: Boot into recovery, and wipe the cache (possible even from stock recovery), maybe some information got stuck there.

Comment: @Izzy yes, clearing cache and dalvik did the trick, thank you - if you post it as an answer, I can accept it.

Comment: Done – glad it solved your issue! See my answer also for more details and a little background ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things like this sometimes happen when something gets stuck in cache. To solve that, the easiest approach is:

1. boot into recovery
2. select to "wipe cache"

Which works for both, stock recovery (aka "3E") and custom recoveries.

Of course, with a custom recovery you can also "wipe Dalvik" – doesn't hurt, just causes a longer first-boot after that. Side effect might even be improved performance, especially when you frequently install/update/uninstall apps, as this wipe forces the entire [dalvik](/questions/tagged/dalvik) cache to be rebuilt cleanly. The important part however is the "normal cache", where it's more common that "things get stuck".

Comment: +1 annnnd the easiest solution is the one I didn't even think of! Fair play Izzy, good simple solution!